# When to use constructor in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the process of learning React.js and would like to better understand class-based `Components`; specifically the `constructor` method (if it is a method). I am coming from Python and I believe it is a little different than the classes there. Is the `__init__` method in Python the same as the `constructor` in React?

During a recent course I followed along on the course dev wrote a `Component` for users registering. This `Component` does *not* call the `constructor` method, but rather initializes state inside the class. It looks like this:

```
class Register extends Component {

    state = {
        username: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        password2: "",
        smsNotifications: true,
        emailNotifications: true,
    }
    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }
```

Now, looking at the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) it says:

> **If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.**"

Why is the constructor not used in this instance? How can I identify when a constructor needs to be used? It seems from looking at the docs that the constructor should almost always be used.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It really *should* say, "If you don't initialize state ***from props*** and you don't bind methods, ...". If you are only setting initial state you don't need to specify a constructor, and using arrow functions "automagically" binds `this` to them, so again, the constructor is unnecessary.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: "*Is the `__init__` method in Python the same as the `constructor` in React?*" - it's the same as the `constructor` in JavaScript, yes. "*This Component does not have a constructor method, but rather initializes state inside the class*" - notice this works quite different than Python. These are known as "class fields" and are just syntactic sugar for initialising properties inside the constructor, without spelling out the `constructor`.

Comment: From what I am reading the transpiler, e.g. Babel, adds the `constructor` later on?